# How to specify a remote CI file configuration in a Github repository

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, travis-ci

What I want to do ?

I'd like to load the `.travis.yml` file configuration from another repository (which I have access too) whenever the build gets triggered

Why ? because I have many repositories with the same `.travis.yml` file, and I don't want to duplicate this file over and over again, would be very painful if I have to make a change in the future, so that's why I would like to have a central configuration file and make all the repositories point to it.

That's the solution I have in mind to the actual problem, but any other idea is more than welcome.

Thanks in advance, cheers!

Comment: You could do it with any file… except `.travis.yml`! You cannot use a submodule (it'd require a separate subdirectory) and without a submodule you need a code that would do `git clone`… but you need the code in `.travis.yml`. Oops!

Comment: @phd yeah after more research I found that is not possible to configure Github to make it point to a remote travis.yml file. I would need to do something much more complex, and it just don't worth it. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: While you cannot keep the ```.travis.yml``` itself in a remote location, you can keep a bunch of bash scripts in repo and the local ```.travis.yml``` then does nothing more than call ```script.bash``` from a cloned repo in its ```script``` section.